# Encryption Algorithm with large key size

Tags: encryption, encryption-symmetric, encryption-asymmetric

I have a 1200 bit key which i would like to use for encrypting data.Is there any encryption algorithm i could use that uses a large key?
The performance of the algorithm does not have to be really good but as long as it uses the entire 1200 bit key,it is good enough.

Comment: That's a very strange, and apparently nonsensical, requirement. Perhaps you can elaborate on why you must use all 1200 bits as is. Note that many key derivation functions can take as input an almost arbitrary number of bits and generate as output keys for standard symmetric encryption algorithms.

Comment: I have a 1200 bit key using which i can uniquely identify a user,so i wanted to use that key to encrypt the users data,i tried using aes 256 but that would mean that i would be cutting down the key size so there would theoretically be a chance of 2 or more users data being encrypted with the same key wouldn't it?Hence i wanted to use the entire key.

Comment: It's *not* the size of the key that matters, it's the entropy in it. Standard crypto key derivation functions are designed to lose at most a negligible amount of entropy when generating keys, up to a maximum of the key size of the underlying algorithm.

Comment: See for example [RFC 5869](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5869)

Comment: @JamesKPolk could you suggest an algorithm that i could use for encryption using this existing key,i am already using aes 256 in cbc mode,The hkdf method looks good but unfortunately i cannot find any code which would do that for me in java,agreed that is a programming problem though.

Comment: If you have a key, you must know what you want to do with it, but your question is currently tagged as [encryption-symmetric] and [encryption-asymmetric]. That doesn't make sense, because those have different use cases. There are many forms of encryption.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming.

Comment: Bouncycastle has an [HKDF class](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/generators/HKDFBytesGenerator.html).

Comment: @JamesKPolk thank you.

Comment: You are combining two unrelated things and this in general reduces security. There should be nothing non-random in a key.

Comment: @zaph There isn't anything non random in the key.

Comment: "a 1200 bit key using which i can uniquely identify a user" is non-random.

Answer (score 1):

Use a key derivation function such as [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) to create a symmetric key from the 1200 bit key.

Then use AES to encrypt the data.